# add sub view in center - iPad

Tags: ipad

I want to add a sub view in current view, this sub view is 300x300. When I add subview using

```
[self.view addSubview:md.view];
```

the md.view will appear at position (0,0) is there any way to add subview in center?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can set view's `center` property:

```
md.view.center = self.view.center;
```

Or you can explicetly set frame for md.view so that it will be centered as you want.

Comment: when i use this, subview doesn't remain on center when I change orientation to landscap! I am using UIActivityView to add it on center. How can I have it center on both orientation?

Comment: @AppleDeveloper, set proper autoresizing mask for the view, or constraints if you use autolayout

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
CGRect bounds = self.view.bounds;
md.view.center = CGPointMake(bounds.size.width / 2, bounds.size.height / 2);
```

before or after that `-addSubview:` line.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify exactly where you want the sub view to be placed within the parent view by doing so in the viewDidLoad method as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   SubView1Controller *subView1Controller=[[[SubView1Controller alloc] initWithNibName:@"SubView1" bundle:nil] autorelease];
   CGRect r = [subView1Controller.view frame];
   r.origin.x = 50;
   r.origin.y = 50;
   [subView1Controller.view setFrame:r];
   [self.view insertSubview:subView1Controller.view atIndex:0]; 
}
```